# Restriction of a semigroup to a form domain

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

Say, we have a Hilbert space $H$ with a semibounded self-adjoint
operator $A:D(A)\to H$ generating a strongly continuous semigroup
$T(t):H\to H$.  Is it possible to restrict $T(t)$ to a form domain of $A$ in such a way that the restriction is again a strongly continuous semigroup, say $T_1(t)$?

How does the generator of $T(t)$ relate to the generator of
$T_1(t)$?  Is the latter self-adjoint w.r.t. a product
$(x,y)_1:=(x,Ay)+(x,y)$?

Is there any relation of $Q(A)$ to the fractional Favard space $F_{1/2}$?

Comment: Thanks to the spectral theorem, it should suffice to consider the case where $A$ is multiplication by a measurable function $h$ which is bounded below.  In that case $T(t)$ is multiplication by $e^{-th}$.  It seems like the question may be easy to answer in that case.  Slogan: "The spectral theorem: reducing functional analysis to measure theory since 1929."

Comment: I should have said, of course, that this is the case where $H = L^2(X, \mu)$ for an arbitrary measure space $(X,\mu)$.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to show most of that using spectral theory but is there any abstract argument for these results?

Comment: @pwl: Well, it is difficult to decide whether an argument is measure theoretical or abstrat, IMHO. Anyway, a more explicit approach to just your questions can be found in §7.1 of a beautiful online lecture note by Arendt:
https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.020/arendt/downloads/internetseminar.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In this case you know that the form domain equals the domain of the square root of $(-A)$.

You can read about the semigroup restricted to this space in an abstract way in Section II.5 of [Engel-Nagel](http://www.fa.uni-tuebingen.de/research/publications/1999/one-parameter-semigroups-for-linear-evolution-equations/engel-nagel_one-parameter-semigroups.pdf).